# Firestore + Proguard + Android billingclient : java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class org.json.JSONObject

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, proguard, in-app-billing

I'm trying to build an app release

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

but it throws me this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class org.json.JSONObject`

I'm trying to save a purchase into Firebase firestore.

1. I have created a POJO PurchasePlan

   ```
   @Keep
   public class PurchasePlan {
       @PropertyName("purchased_on")
       public Date purchased_on;
       @PropertyName("email_id")
       public String email_id;
       @PropertyName("pro_plan_id")
       public String pro_plan_id;
       @PropertyName("is_acknowledged")
       public boolean is_acknowledged;
       @PropertyName("applied_promo_code")
       public String applied_promo_code;
       @PropertyName("pro_plan_price")
       public String pro_plan_price;
       @PropertyName("pro_plan_details")
       public SkuDetails pro_plan_details;
       @PropertyName("cancelled_on")
       public Date cancelled_on;
   }
   ```
2. I save the PurchasePlan object to firestore

   ```
   private void savePurchase() {
       FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
       if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
           db.collection(PAID_USERS_DEBUG).add(plan);
       } else {
           db.collection(PAID_USERS).add(plan);
       }
   }
   ```

The app keeps crashing and won't save the object to the firestore collection. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to this. This R8 compatibility [faq](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/master/compatibility-faq.md) helped.
Also, [this](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg).

I added the following lines to my proguard-rules.

```
-keep class com.<package_name>.models.** { <fields>; }

-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
```